# Accessing member function from member function array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, member

I have grouped several member functions into an array. How do I access a function from the array? I am getting 'error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments.' See below.

```c
class A
{
public:

    //Constructor
    A()
    {
        //Fill function array
        ClipFunction[0] = &A::ClipTop;
        ClipFunction[1] = &A::ClipBottom;
        ClipFunction[2] = &A::ClipLeft;
        ClipFunction[3] = &A::ClipRight;
    }

    //Declare array
    typedef void (A::*ClipFunction_ptr) ();
    ClipFunction_ptr ClipFunction[4];

    //Clipping functions
    void ClipTop();
    void ClipBottom();
    void ClipLeft();
    void ClipRight();

    //Start clipping process
    void StartClip();

};

//Define clipping functions
void A::ClipTop() {}
void A::ClipBottom() {}
void A::ClipLeft() {}
void A::ClipRight() {}

//Define A::StartClip()
void A::StartClip()
{
    //Run through all functions in the array
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        ClipFunction[i](); //ERROR. How do I access ClipFunction[i] ???
    }

}
```

Comment: Why would you do something so ugly in the first place? :( I think you can mess around with http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function for such a task, if it's really required... Also, I have a feeling that your current implementation never deallocates the `ClipFunction` array...

Comment: @MihaiTodor You're right! I wasn't deallocating the array.

Comment: Which is correct, as the array is not dynamically allocated, so it does not have to be deallocated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879431/how-to-destruct-an-array

Comment: @IvanVergiliev Yeah, you're right. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you need use "this" explicitly as in http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/topic/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/cplr034.htm .

So in your case, you should use

```
    (this ->* ClipFunction[i]) ();
```

instead of

```
    ClipFunction[i]();
```

PS

When I reply this post, I didn't see Vite Falcon's answer. Basically we are saying the same thing but I don't think his code  " this->(*ClipFunction[i])()" will compile because GCC gives errors on my machine.   "(this->*ClipFunction[i])()" is the correct form.

Answer (score 3):

You need to dereference the function like this:

`this->(*ClipFunction[i])();`

What you're missing is the `this` or rather the compiler is complaining that it doesn't have the first parameter (the instance of the object invoking the member function) to pass it to the function.

To the compiler the member function:

`void A::ClipFunction()
{
}`

translates to something like:
`void ClipFunction(A* this)
{
}`

Hence the error complaining that the function is not one that takes zero arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want the scope resolution operator `::` in your typedef. Instead try putting

```
    typedef void (*ClipFunction_ptr) ();
```